# Parse Swift IOS - PFCloud callFunctionInBackground Selector not invoked

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, selector, parse-cloud-code

When i call the PFcloud function from normal it return the correct count how ever when i call it with selector, the selector call back function is not fired,

Appreciate if any can can point to me what is the mistake in my code.

### Working block - it print out the count successfully

```
        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground(CloudFunctions.getBookingCount, withParameters: ["camp": "pmAwLDTNc6"], block: {
        (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if ( error === nil) {
            NSLog("Booking Count call back: \(result) ")
        }
        else if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("error in helloWorld: \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
```

### Not Working block (Selector ) - selector function not called

```
    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground(CloudFunctions.getBookingCount, withParameters: ["camp": "pmAwLDTNc6"], target: self, selector: "block:")


func block (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) {
    if ( error === nil) {
        NSLog("Booking Count from Block: \(result) ")
    }
    else if (error != nil) {
        NSLog("error in helloWorld: \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

### Question:

I need someone to highlight to my the error in writing the selector function as the selector function is not called.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your method has two parameters so you need a selector like `blockWithResult:error:`

Answer (score -3):

You're not using the right Swift syntax for selector. Try this instead:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground(CloudFunctions.getBookingCount, withParameters: ["camp": "pmAwLDTNc6"], target: self, selector: Selector("block:error:"))

func block(result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) {
    if ( error === nil) {
        NSLog("Booking Count from Block: \(result) ")
    }
    else if (error != nil) {
        NSLog("error in helloWorld: \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```