# parse.com cloud coding conversion from objective c to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

In my swift app, I am sending mail to the registered mail ID which is register in parse.com. I searched in docs, Objective c code is having. I couldn't convert it into SWIFT. I am receiving error. My code is below.

```
//OBJECTIVE C
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"hello"
                   withParameters:@{}
                            block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
   if (!error) {
     // result is @"Hello world!"
   }
}];

//MY SWIFT CODING

PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", withParameters: {}, block: {(result: String, error: NSError)} )

//ERROR RECEIVING that conversion not happening.
```

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393453/parse-swift-ios-pfcloud-callfunctioninbackground-selector-not-invoked

Comment: .self to reference the type object, If we accept, [block: {(result: String.self, error: NSError.self)}] then another error, "Tuples types (AnyObject!, NSError! and '( )') have different number of elements"

Comment: PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("contact_form", withParameters: ["name":"abc", "email":"bcd@cd.co", "message":"xyz"], block: {
                    (result : AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in   })   I am trying in SWIFT. Is this syntax is right???  @ Dharmesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your syntax of the `withParameter` tag. You need to use `[:]` instead of `{}`. Also change the type from the result to `AnyObject!`

I highly recommend you to check [this developer guide of parse](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#cloudfunctions/iOS), where you find all the neccessary informations. Just choose "Swift" as the language to show. You can choose to show Objective-c or Swift sample code in this guide.

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", withParameters:[:]) {
  (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    // result is "Hello world!"
  }
}
```

Comment: if  I run my code, I am getting error in debug area. ""Error Domain=Parse Code=141 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 141.)" UserInfo=0x7fc1ca5099b0 {error=function not found, code=141} ""

Comment: That means that this function wasn't found in your cloudcode. you should check the quickstart-guide etc. for help

Answer (score 0):

for swift 2.0 try this

```
 PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("GetUserIntrest", withParameters:nil) {
        (result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // result is "Hello world!"
        }
    }
```